# After removing lxc device, still managed to access device from its boundary directory

Tags: linux, mount, lxc, unmount, lxd

I am using Lxd container for my sd card access in Linux based device.
i mounted sd card with following commands

> mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/flash/sdcard.

> lxc config device add dhaneesh2  sda disk path=/mnt/sda/ source=/mnt/flash/sdcard

after this sd card can access from lxd container

when i try to remove sd card with following commands

> lxc config device remove dhaneesh sda

> umount /mnt/flash/sdcard

sd card unmount successfully
but if i open lxd container terminal  i am inside
cd /mnt/sda folder
then i try to remove container and apply unmount command still i can access sd card /mnt/sda folder also i can read and write data to it

how to solve this issue

Comment: Filesystems that are in use cannot be unmounted normally. That’s probably the problem here.

Comment: yes, any solution for this issue or is there any way to find mount pont is in use or busy